# QuickCheck: defining Arbitrary instance in terms of other Arbitraries

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm using QuickCheck 1 and I've got the following data types:

```
data A = ...
instance Arbitrary A where ...
data B = ...
instance Arbitrary B where ...
data C = C A B
```

Now I'd like to define an `Arbitrary` instance for `C` so that `C` values are generated using existing generators for `A` and `B`. I ended up doing this:

```
instance Arbitrary C where
  arbitrary = elements [(C a b) |
                        a <- generate 20 (System.Random.mkStdGen 0) arbitrary,
                        b <- generate 20 (System.Random.mkStdGen 0) arbitrary]
```

Is this explicit generation of a fixed number of values for `A` and `B` necessary, or is there a better way of combining existing `Arbitraries` into a new one?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
instance Arbitrary C
  where arbitrary = do a <- arbitrary
                       b <- arbitrary
                       return (C a b)
```

Although sclv's idea of using `liftM2` from Control.Monad is probably better:

```
instance Arbitrary C
  where arbitrary = liftM2 C arbitrary arbitrary
```

Comment: `arbitrary = C <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary` -- applicative ftw!

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I like the applicative solution even more but sadly it doesn't work in QuickCheck 1 since `Gen` was not an instance of `Applicative` back then.

Comment: sclv beat me to it. Applicatives can be very powerful and expressive.